# How to change the skin on VS2010

Tags: colors, themes, visual-studio-2010

The dark and light contrast on the VS2010 IDE is not as comfortable on the eyes as the previous versions.

Any way of changing the colors on the IDE skin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378

Answer (score 2):

[StudioStyles](http://studiostyles.info/) has a large number of user submitted colour schemes available in VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010 formats.

Their [FAQ](http://studiostyles.info/home/faq) has instructions on how to apply the schemes:

> **I can't open the .vssettings theme
> file I downloaded. What do I do with
> it?**
>
> You need to import the settings into
> Visual Studio. This might look like a
> lot of work, but it's pretty easy
> after you do it a couple of times.
>
> 1. In Visual Studio, choose *Tools >
>    Import and Export Settings*
> 2. Choose
>    *Import Selected Environment Settings*
>    and select whether you want to back up
>    your existing settings or not
> 3. Click
>    *Browse...* to choose the file you
>    downloaded.
> 4. You get a choice which
>    settings you want to import - choose
>    all of them since the file only
>    contains color settings and won't
>    touch your other VS settings.
> 5. Click
>    *Finish* and you'll see the new colors.
>
> *Note:* if you save the file to *My
> Documents > Visual Studio 2010 >
> Settings*, you'll have quick access to
> choose the settings file in step 3
> above.

[Coding Horror 2010](http://studiostyles.info/schemes/coding-horror-2010) is my particular favourite right now

Answer (score 2):

- [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor (Free)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378)
- [Create and share Visual Studio color schemes](http://studiostyles.info/)
- [Visual Studio 2010 - Community Wallpapers](http://vs2010wallpapers.com/)

Enjoy.

Comment: 2 of your 3 links are already in previous answers!

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman posted a very good blog entry on this very subject yesterday!

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeTheVisualStudio2010IDEColorsLookLikeVisualStudio2008.aspx